# Not understanding one step in derivation of Dirichlet kernel

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, exponential-function

I was reading some notes on the Dirichlet Kernel and they have a proof of how it reduces to 
$\sin(2\pi(N+ 1/2)t)/\sin(\pi t)$. I could follow the steps except for one early step which
is the following:

$$D_{N}(t) = \sum_{n=-N}^{n=N} e^{ 2 \pi i n t} = e^{-2 \pi i Nt} \sum_{n=0}^{n=2N} e^{2 \pi i n t}$$

The first equals sign is by the definition of the Dircihlet kernel. But I don't understand how the second wequality is obtained. Thanks and I'm sorry for this question. I just hate to skip steps of proofs without understanding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called *index shift*. Introduce $m=n+N$. Since $n$ runs from $-N$ to $N$, the new index $m$ runs from $0$ to $2N$. So,

$$\sum_{n=-N}^{n=N} e^{ 2 \pi i n t} = \sum_{m=0}^{m=2N} e^{ 2 \pi i (m-N) t} = \sum_{m=0}^{m=2N} e^{ 2 \pi i m t}e^{ -2 \pi i N t}$$
Here we see the common factor $e^{ -2 \pi i N t}$ and move it outside to get 
$$e^{ -2 \pi i N t}\sum_{m=0}^{m=2N} e^{ 2 \pi i m t}$$
Lastly, the indices are [dummy variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/536868/147263); it does not matter how they are called. So the last formula may just as well be written 
$$e^{ -2 \pi i N t}\sum_{n=0}^{n=2N} e^{ 2 \pi i n t}$$

Comment: thank you. really nice explanation.